# Create FileHandle from fd in Node.js

Tags: node.js, fs

If I have opened file by `const fd = fs.openSync(...)` is it possible to get a `FileHandle` object from `fd` somehow and continue by `await fileHandle.writev(...)`? I have some existing code using `FileHandle` but need to do sync file open.

Note: I know I can `util.promisify(fs)` and use `await fs.writev(fd, ...)`, but I would need to rewrite the old code, then.